# JedisPool number of connections issue

Tags: java, redis, pool

am new to redis and use a JedisPool in my multi-threaded app.

```
 JedisPoolConfig config = new JedisPoolConfig();
 config.setMaxActive(200);
 config.setMaxIdle(200);
 pool = new JedisPool(config,"localhost",6379,-1,jedisPasswd);
```

I want to have 200 connections with out getting expired, but at any
time I don't have more than 2 to 3 connections, Do I miss anything
here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using setMinIdle() ?